# How to use Google Drive Rest API v3 in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have not found any documentation related to apply Google drive rest API v3 for uploading data in Android using kotlin. Please anyone.Anything will help.

Comment: Did you find what you need?

Comment: not exactly and i really don't remember how i did it , but i took help of a site its written in java i converted it to kotlin and it worked. i also wrote some codes on my own.   https://ammar.lanui.online/integrate-google-drive-rest-api-on-android-app-bc4ddbd90820      . check this site , hope this helps

Comment: Oh, thx, but I already implemented it. I asked because I thought that you still didn't find a solution. https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/setup-android-google-drive-rest-api/ this helped me. Just for information. Your link is useful too, so thank you :)